# Variable substitution in Maven

Tags: xml, maven, apigee

I'm new to maven and I'm trying to change the content of a field based on the entry provided in the command line by using a variable.

I have the following xml file called weatherxml.xml in the directory apiproxy:

```
<APIProxy name="weatherxml">?
    <ConfigurationVersion majorVersion="4" minorVersion="0"/>
    <CreatedAt>1453818052</CreatedAt>
    <Description>${description}</Description>
    <DisplayName>weatherxml</DisplayName>
    <validate>true</validate>
</APIProxy>
```

And in the pom.xml file I have this piece of code:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>apiproxy</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

This is the test profile used for building

```
<profile>
  <id>test</id>
  <properties>
    <apigee.profile>test</apigee.profile>
    <apigee.env>${api_environment}</apigee.env>
    <apigee.hosturl>${api_hosturl}</apigee.hosturl>
    <apigee.apiversion>v1</apigee.apiversion> <!-- value of version in  https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v2 -->
    <apigee.org>${api_organization}</apigee.org>
    <apigee.username>${username}</apigee.username>
    <apigee.password>${password}</apigee.password>
    <apigee.options>override</apigee.options>
    <apickli.env>.test</apickli.env>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

If I invoke maven by using

```
mvn resources:resources -Ddescription="Test description"
```

it creates the target directory and I can see the change has been made. However, if I invoke

```
mvn install -Ptest -Dusername=xxx -Dpassword=yyy -Dhost=www.aaa.com -Ddescription="Test description"
```

it builds and deploys the code but the description field contains the "${description}" text instead of "Test description".

How could I get the variable substitution in the deployed code? I don't know if this could be related by the use of the plugins, maybe some of them overrides it.

```
<build>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>apiproxy</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g</groupId>
                <artifactId>apigee-edge-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement> 

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>

                 <!--Copy the full apiproxy folder to target folder -->
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-apiproxy-resources</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                         <!--this is important -->
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                         <!--target -->
                        <outputDirectory>${target.root.dir}/apiproxy</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                 <!--source -->
                                <directory>${project.root.dir}/apiproxy</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>                            
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g</groupId>
            <artifactId>apigee-edge-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                 <!--Use this module level config to skip module build. Make it true -->
                <skip>false</skip> 
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>configure-bundle-step</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>configure</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                 <!--deploy bundle -->
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-bundle-step</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- cleaning dirs -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>auto-clean-init</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>auto-clean-install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- run cucumber / apickli tests -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- run integration tests -->
                <execution>
                    <id>integration</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <NODE_ENV>
                                ${apigee.env}
                            </NODE_ENV>
                        </environmentVariables>
                        <executable>cucumber-js</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>
                            tests/integration${apickli.env} --format json:cucumber-result.json
                        </commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Could be that the `test` profile is overriding it. Try by cleaning first `mvn clean install -Ptest -Dusername=xxx -Dpassword=yyy -Dhost=www.aaa.com -Ddescription="Test description"` and post the profile configuration of `test`.

Comment: Don't forget to `clean`. This might be the issue, who knows. (see comment above).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've tried the clean but not working

Comment: In your pom you also have a further execution of the resource plugin with a binding to the package phase without filtering and with overriding, which is probably the cause of the issue and the difference between the two maven executions you mentioned, can you test that?

Comment: @A. Di Matteo: Thanks, I'll have to check this.